# Good places to download .vhd images with different operating systems?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vhd

I'm running virtualbox and have found it slightly inconvenient to have to create a new VHD and perform an OS install for every single *nix flavor (or other operating systems) that i want to use.

Is there a site somewhere that aggregates .vhds for download?

Comment: I can only find Windows 7 .vhd download link from Microsoft. 
Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=11575. Just run part01.exe to merge all parts to one file.

Comment: There are a few in the JSON file in the text (search for "See a sample gallery entry here") at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/custom-gallery. See https://ubuntu.com/blog/optimised-ubuntu-desktop-images-available-in-microsoft-hyper-v-gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find several images at **[VirtualBoxImages.com](http://virtualboximages.com/)**

Comment: unfortunately no windows-related

Comment: domain unavailable :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are a bit nostalgic you can also download OS/2 and a Windows 98 Live CD VHD images here:
[Internet Archive](http://archive.org/search.php?query=vhd%20AND%20subject:%22VHD%22)

Just note that the the Windows 98 Live cd doesn't have much to speak of in terms of software.

Also both VHD images are under 20MB each!